# How to configure SMTP settings based on web hosting's mail account

Tags: php, email, smtp

Hello how do i configure my php mailer to make it work with these settings? [image]

i tried to fix the username and password but i still get this error 
PHPMailer Error: The following From address failed: thesis@thesis.buybranded.com.ph : Called Mail() without being connected

```
<?php
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'gowebph.gowebph.com'; // "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" didn't worked
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
// or try these settings (worked on XAMPP and WAMP):
// $mail->Port = 465;
// $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';


$mail->Username = "thesis@thesis.buybranded.com.ph";
$mail->Password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails
$mail->SingleTo = true; // if you want to send a same email to multiple users. multiple emails will be sent one-by-one.

$mail->From = "thesis@thesis.buybranded.com.ph";
$mail->FromName = "Your Name";

$mail->addAddress("vince_agno@live.com","User 1");
$mail->addAddress("2009010067@ust-ics.mygbiz.com","User 2");

$mail->Subject = "Testing PHPMailer with localhost";
$mail->Body = "Hi,<br /><br />This system is working perfectly.";

if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
    echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Comment: Try to add $mail->SMTPDebug = 4; to enable verbose debug output. That may give you a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your port & protocol mismatched. port 465 is for ssl and port 587 is for tls.
see https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13287?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Could you please use this

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
```

also

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
```

Or if using TLS try to use port 587 for TLS

from wiki ---Secure SMTP - port 587 (can also use the legacy port 465 - this may solve problems with SSL) (port 587 has optional TLS encryption, possibly using STARTTLS now, or use port 465 for SSL encryption)